# Need a step-by-step WCF as Windows Service

Tags: windows, wcf, service, installation

I'm trying to find a (good) step-by-step example of creating a WCF and hosting it as a Windows Service (with installer). I'm using VS2010 and have a simple WCF with 1 function (just returns 'Hello').

Please don't Google and post; I'm looking for a resource someone has actually used. Most of the Googling I've done hasn't turned up much for what I'm trying to do.

I just want to take my WCF library, and find a way to install it as a Window Service. I've done it in 2008, but 2010 is... Different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to host the wcf contract class in your onstart method of service calling `ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(YourClass)` and in `onclose` method of your service you need call `host.close()`. The hosting option depends on what type of clients you want to talk to if you want to talk to pure html clients using REST you need to host your service in `WebServiceHost` and the binding you need to use in that case is `webHttpBinding`.

I have followed the following example and was able to create windows service hosted wcf and im sure this what you are looking for [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)

I did not find any difference in creating wcf service in vs2008 and vs2010.

What type of clients do you want to talk and which protocols do you want to support. This all defines your configuration.

Comment: btw which OS are you using for your development environment? Visual studio should be running as administrator if you have to debug and run your application because registering of namespace in your machine requires admin privileges.

Comment: +1 votes for both the answer and comment, THAT was the link I was so desperately searching for and I'd forgotten to run VS as admin. Kudos to both!!!

Answer (score 7):

For future reference - for anyone else looking at this thread:

Here is the best example I've found for what this question was looking for:
[CodeProject: WCF Service with Windows Service Hosting, consumed from C# App](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24349/Generic-WCF-Host)!

This link mentioned above shows how to consume the WCF service, but with a lot of other stuff to wade through: 
[MSDN: How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx#Y382)!

This second link above is good for creating the WCF service, but not for consuming it: 
[MSDN: Hosting and Consuming WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx)!

I rarely find MSDN articles that I like :-)

Comment: Second link "MSDN: How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service" FTW!

Answer (score 0):

What I've used when I use WCF in a Windows Service is [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/documentation/getting-started/) as a Windows service framework and a modified version of [this Code Project code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx) to dynamically host, install and run WCF services.

Topshelf makes it very easy to develop and debug because it can be run as a console application. Being able to dynamically update WCF service libraries without stopping the Windows service is just cool.  ;)

Comment: google this since I don't have code handy but it's not hard https://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/creating-a-wcf-calculator-in-a-windows-service-with-topshelf/